# Setting up route in backend for a search bar function

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

I am having issues with setting up routes for a search bar function, it returns 404.

Routes

```
    import express from "express";
    const router = express.Router();
    const { searchUserandPost } = require('../controllers/search.js'); 
    import { verifyToken } from "../middleware/auth.js";
    
    router.get('/search', verifyToken, searchUserandPost);
    
    export default router;
```

Controller

```
    import Post from "../models/Post.js";
    import User from "../models/User.js";
    
    export const searchUserandPost = async (req, res) => {
    
        try{
            const { keyword } = req.query;
    
            const posts = await Post.find({ description: { $regex: keyword, $options: 'i' } });
    
            const users = await User.find({ $or: [
              { firstName: { $regex: keyword, $options: 'i' } },
              { lastName: { $regex: keyword, $options: 'i' } },
            ] });
          
            res.status(200).json({ posts, users });
        } catch(err) {
            console.error('Error during search:', error);
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal server error' });
        }
    }
```

I have checked it does run on port 3001 and other functions runs perfectly fine with the port 3001.

frontend

```
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/search?query=${searchQuery}`, {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            
          },
        });
        console.log(response)
        if (response.ok) {
          const data = await response.json();
          setSearchResults(data); 
        } else {
          console.error('Error fetching search results');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during search:');
      }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a mismatch in your query string. You are using [Object destructuring](https://javascript.info/destructuring-assignment#object-destructuring) to take the `keyword` from the `req.query` object but you are sending the query with the word `query` instead of `keyword`.

You can either change this:

```
// await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/search?query=${searchQuery}` //< replace this
await fetch(`http://localhost:3001/search?keyword=${searchQuery}` //< with this
```

or this:

```js
// const { keyword } = req.query; //< replace this
const { query } = req.query;      //< with this
```

Either of these changes will work but **not** **both**.

As for the `404` make sure you have mounted the router at `/` because this is where your front-end is sending the request, for example:

```js
import router from './router.js';
//..
app.use('/', router);
```